# How to use isPresent() with get.getValue()

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm applying `filter` and `max` on a `List<Person>`, trying to find out oldest person(people) among the suspected list if he's on the target list

```
List<String> targetNames= new ArrayList<>();
targetPersonName.add("Jason");
targetPersonName.add("Mike");

List<Person> suspectedList = getSuspectedPeople();
List<Person> result = suspectedList.stream()
                .filter((Person p) -> targetNames.contains(p.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getAge))
                .entrySet().stream().max(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()).get().getValue();
```

The above code works fine when `result` is not `null` or not `empty`; however, it raise the `NoSuchElementException("No value present")` when `result` is empty. Looking for a way to use `ifPresent()` then `get().getValue()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` to transform the entry to the list and `orElseGet` to return an empty list if the max entry does not exist.

```java
List<Person> result = suspectedList.stream()
    .filter(p -> targetNames.contains(p.getName()))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getAge))
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .max(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
    .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
    .orElseGet(ArrayList::new);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have many options.

1. Save `Optional` to variable and then check if present.

```
Optional<Map.Entry> optional = suspectedList.stream()
                .filter((Person p) -> targetNames.contains(p.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getAge))
                .entrySet().stream().max(Map.Entry.comparingByKey());
if (optional.isPresent()) {
  List<Person> result = optional.get().getValue();
}
```

2. Use [Optional.orElse()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) to supply default value, if empty.
3. Use [Optional.orElseGet()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-) to calculate default value, if empty.

```
List<Person> result = suspectedList.stream()
                .filter((Person p) -> targetNames.contains(p.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getAge))
                .entrySet().stream().max(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
                .orElseGet(() -> generate default value)
                .getValue();
```

4. Or [Optional.orElseThrow()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-) to throw custom exception, if your use case requires it, if empty.
5. Use [Optional.map()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-), the function will be applied only if there is value in the optional.

```
List<Person> result = suspectedList.stream()
                .filter((Person p) -> targetNames.contains(p.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getAge))
                .entrySet().stream().max(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
                .map(entry -> entry.getValue())
                .orElseGet(ArrayList::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use orElse function and set it to Entry with empty list

```java
.orElse(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(0, Collections.emptyList())).getValue()
```

So the full function in Java 8 will look like this

```java
List<Person> result = suspectedList.stream()
                .filter((Person p) -> targetNames.contains(p.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getAge))
                .entrySet().stream().max(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()).orElse(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(0, Collections.emptyList())).getValue();
```

The value of result will be EmptyList

Answer (score 0):

I think It would be better for you to first sort your collection based on field that You are looking for, then you can easily get result from the sorted collection!!

```
List<Person> sortedList = personList.stream()
  .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge).reversed())
  .collect(Collectors.toList());

Person maxAgePerson = sortedList.get(0);
```